# How do you make SWT Scale Component have a transparent background?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to use an SWT Scale Component (the slider thingy) over a canvas with a drawn image, the scale is used to zoom in and out on the canvas, so I want the grey area around the ruler to inherit the drawn image from the canvas behind and I can't, I have tried the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975980/java-swt-composite-how-to-set-a-control-to-a-transparent-background) but that seems to inherit the background colour but still draw the square around it rather than not drawing anything on that space.

Here's a screenshot in an example of this issue:

[image]

This code to produce the above window:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scale;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ScaleExample extends Canvas{

    public ScaleExample(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                ScaleExample.this.paintControl(e);
            }
        });

        this.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
        Scale zoomRule = new Scale(this, SWT.VERTICAL);
        zoomRule.setMinimum(1);
        zoomRule.setMaximum(18);
        zoomRule.setIncrement(1);
        Point p = zoomRule.computeSize(40, 200);
        zoomRule.setBounds(10, 10, p.x, p.y);
    }

    protected void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        GC gc = e.gc;

        Point size = getSize();
        int width = size.x, height = size.y;

        gc.drawOval(0, 0, width, height);        

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Scale Example");
        shell.setSize(new Point(300, 300));
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        shell.setLayout(layout);
        ScaleExample se = new ScaleExample(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        se.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();

        }
        display.dispose();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post your code and a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: I can't really post my code, I can try and recreate it in a little application, but essential I've put a Scale Component on to a Canvas that has been painted too and the Scale square is a solid block.

Comment: Huh, I see. Well, I don't know a solution, but my guess would be that this isn't possible. But maybe someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: Do you know of a better component to use that might lessen the impact of this issue?

Comment: Not really, no. Personally, I would place the scale outside the canvas, but I don't know if that's a feasible solution for you.

Comment: It's for a widget that displays tiles from a Map server that I am developing, becasue its using a local hosted set of tiles they can take a while to generate so the indication that something is actually happening when users inevitably get impatient and start scrolling the mouse up and down will be invaluable. Since most web based maps have a zoom level indicator super imposed on the image I wanted one to, I may just have to custom draw something on to it.